# Why VBA doubleclick stopped working suddenly?

Tags: excel, vba

Below piece of code suddenly stopped working, please help?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

On Error Resume Next
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 27 And Target.Row < 70 Then
        UserForm1.Show
        Target.Value = returnvalue
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Sam. Stopped working is not enough for us to help. Is there an error? Which line is causing the error? What is the error message?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: UserForm is not being displayed on doubleClick for cells B28 to B69

Comment: Delete "on error resume next" and then what error do you get?

Comment: If nothing happens at all it is worth checking if events are enabled. Using the Immediate window in VBA Editor type ‘Debug.Print Application.EnableEvents’.  If it returns False then you will need to type ‘Application.EnableEvents = True’ and it should start working again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. I was using a dictionary to populate a list box in the initialize block of the form. The range used to build the dictionary had duplicates causing the code to fail. Updating the code to handle duplicates solved my problem.